# Post request fails if user waits a minute before submitting post to server (IE only)

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, fetch, single-page-application

I am building a SPA that is backed by a .net webapi using windows authentication hosted in IIS.

When the user hits the home page, it is calling the api via Fetch and getting some data.

Fiddler tells me this i done with `Persistant-Auth: true`.

When the user clicks a button on the page, it is then posts to the server and creates a record in the database for the user.

Here's the strange thing (Internet Explorer only)...

If the user clicks the button within a minute it will succeed.

- Fiddler shows it has used `Persistant-Auth: true`

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Expires: -1
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   Persistent-Auth: true
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 16:34:02 GMT
>   Content-Length: 2

If the user has waited a minute on the homepage it will fail.

- Fiddler shows it tried and failed (401) Session-Based-Authentication

> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
>   Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>   WWW-Authenticate: NTLM SOMERANDOMTOKEN
>   Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 16:35:30 GMT
>   Content-Length: 341
>   Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

- And then it tried again and failed (408)

> HTTP/1.1 408 Request body incomplete
>   Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2017 16:35:30 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Connection: close
>   Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
>   Timestamp: 16:35:30.878

Any ideas why this happens and how one would avoid it?